# ¿Una variable puede usarse en distintos bucles?

Tags: c#, variables, bucles

Se que es muy básico, pero acabo de empezar con programación. 
Seria sobre c#.

Quiero hacer una cuenta atrás desde un numero a 0 usando 3 bucles distintos que se encuentran en un mismo método (button1_Click). ¿Puedo usar la y como variable para los 3 bucles?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);

        for (int y = a; y >= 0; y--)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(y.ToString());
        }

        int y=a;
        while (y<=a && y>=0 ){
            richTextBox2.AppendText(y.ToString());
            y--;
        }

        do while{
            int y=a;
            richTextBox3.AppendText(y.ToString());
            y--;
        }(y<=a && y>=0);

    }
```

Porque en int y=a; me indica "Error 1   No se puede declarar una variable local denominada 'y' en este ámbito, porque daría un significado diferente a 'y', que ya se utiliza en un ámbito 'secundario' con otra denotación"

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3):

El tema pasa por el ambito en el cual declaras las variable, debes hacerlo de uan forma consistente, no puedes declarar una variable en un ambitlo local y luego querer hacerlo en uno global

Cuando defines el `int y` dentro del `for`, defines la variable de forma local a ese bloque de codigo, pero despues cuando lo defines para el while lo quiere ampliar el ambito haciendolo global (por eso lo defines por fuera)

Si tienes que una misma variables local y global siempre deberias ir por el ambito mas abarcativo, pero debes ser consistente, sino usa distintos nombres de variables

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);

    int y = a;

    for (y = a; y >= 0; y--)
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText(y.ToString());
    }

    y=a;
    while (y<=a && y>=0 ){
        richTextBox2.AppendText(y.ToString());
        y--;
    }

   y=a;
    do {
        richTextBox3.AppendText(y.ToString());
        y--;
    } while(y<=a && y>=0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para solventar este error puedes declarar la variable Y antes del ciclo for.
De esta manera la puedes usar en los tres ciclos posteriores.
Ejemplo:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        int y = 0;

        for ( y = a; y >= 0; y--)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(y.ToString());
        }

        y=a;
        while (y<=a && y>=0 ){
            richTextBox2.AppendText(y.ToString());
            y--;
        }
        y=a;
        do while{
            richTextBox3.AppendText(y.ToString());
            y--;
        }(y<=a && y>=0);
    }
```